# How to convert dictionary with integer keys to readable file?

Tags: python, file

my code is generating a TypeError that it cannot unpack non-iterable integer objects

```
BMI = {
  15: 'underweight',
  23: 'normal weight',
  24: 'normal weight'
  }

with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
  for k,v in BMI:
    out.write('%s : %s \n' %(k, v))
```

My desirable output in a text file would look like this:

```
15: underweight
23: normal weight
24: normal weight
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate through the dict items (both keys and values). Use `for k, v in BMI.items()`.